# In firefox dev console only [object Request] is displayed (no options to expand)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When logging service worker's fetch event.request, in firefox's web console only `[object Request]` is displayed. Can't find any option to expand that object or interact with it in any way.

In chrome, it is displayed as `Request {method: "GET", url: ...}` with options to expand.

Is there a way to get similar functionality in firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `console.log(obj)`,
use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))`
as per MDN's web docs.

Should've read them before I've submitted the question, but it might help others.